# Android tablet with little endian wrong color format

Tags: android, c++, colors, opengl-es, rgba

I'm writing gles2 application, which works fine on every device except Galaxy Notes.
Colors seems to be not RGBA, but some kind of ABGR (more like ABGA)
[image: blue buttons drawn yellow, black titles are red]

blue buttons drawn yellow, black titles are red (sorry for posting photo, but screenshot are showing right colors, which is odd)

I'm using offscreen buffer to draw everything on it and then draw this buffer's image on screen.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, m_width, m_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)
```

this is how i use texImage2d for textures.

I've written some test app and what shows screenshot:
[image]

and this is how it looks in real life
[image]

Comment: And what exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636847/odd-results-using-glteximage2d) .

In particular, it seems you lose endianess if you use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. If what you're doing is store 4 bytes in an int, then you should use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` instead. Then it will know in which order to expect them for that platform.

Comment: Thank you, but gles, unfortunately has no UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8. But it have GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4. Should i use it instead? (and, ofc, change my data to packed short)

Comment: You are missing an _8 in `UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8`, there should be 4 of them. Maybe this explains why you weren't finding it?

Comment: no no... just forgot one, while was writing... there are 8_8_8_ in OpenGL, but according to khronos manulas "Specifies the data type of the texel data. The following symbolic values are accepted: GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, and GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1." Also, it seems there is a possibility to set GL_BGRA as format in gles 3.0, but i'm using 2.0. So my assumtion is to use short instead of int and try using 4_4_4_4. Hope it will work.

Comment: Fingers crossed :)